# AWS codeartifact Failed to update checksum metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, build, metadata, aws-codeartifact

I need help with the configuration of the code artifact, whenever I try to deploy through maven it shows an error [WARNING] Failed to upload checksum maven-metadata.xml. But artifacts still get published in the snapshot with status build success.

Is there anything I am doing wrong,
any help or guidance will be appreciated.